# Accessing HttpContext in a class library - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am populating an instance of a class that represents the session variable and exists in a class library. I need to populate one property that requires me to get access to the `Request` object. I understand that I can use the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request` to get the request object?

Is this a good practice. Something tells me that I should be doing this in the controller (or the base controller) that has the `System.Web` namespace.

Answer (score 12):

Its not a bad practice - the object is available - if you design dictates to access it there - then by all means do it. One option is to pass in an instance of the request to the class's constructor if it makes you feel cleaner : )

Comment: Doesn't this couple the class library to the `System.Web` namespace. Is it a valid argument to say that in future, if this class library is moved outside of the web project, then it wouldn't know anything about the `HttpContext` object

Comment: I tend to use the prinicple of If You Don't Need It Now, Don't Write It Now.  You can always refactor later. If you need to refactor references to HttpContext in the future, you'll have to do whatever you're doing with the HttpContext a different way. That will mean you'll need a new interface class for whatever you're trying to do, with an implementation of the interface for web and an implementation of the interface for windows forms or whatever. But my input is, do it when you know you need it. Don't try to guess what you might need someday maybe.

Comment: if you want to decouple, then write to an interface or another class that acts as a proxy (the Adapter pattern) but its your call. In all the 'theory' its very very rare that I will have to swap out a full implementation so the 'well what if' scenario that its proper to code to protect against.. sometimes never comes up : ) if you realllllly feel it could change in the future.. then just write to an intermediate object, otherwise, use the context.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Teemu Keiski](http://forums.asp.net/members/joteke.aspx) on the ASP.NET forums:

> You could use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` but that's bad practise
>   since it makes your class library totally unusable outside web
>   applications (and if you access Sessions via that, it also gets
>   unusable for web services in most scenarios).
>
> Anything you pass by getting straight HttpContext could be passed as
>   parameters into the class that needs it. And if you need to access
>   Response object directly, you could pass `Response.OutputStream` into
>   the class (which would take it as general Stream object)

<sup>Source: http://forums.asp.net/post/1311405.aspx</sup>

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt to cite where you copied and pasted this from: http://forums.asp.net/t/998446.aspx/1

Answer (score 6):

Fundamentally there's nothing wrong with this as long as you take a dependency on `System.Web.Abstractions` and pass into your class a reference to `HttpRequestBase`. The classes in this assembly are not sealed and all members are virtual which means your class will still be testable.

More info in the answers to the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720991/system-web-abstractions-what-is-it-good-for)